# Custom nav bar background is not restored when popping view

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am having trouble with my navigation toolbar.  I set the navigation toolbar background image in my app delegate, and then have a button that, when clicked, changes the navigation tool bar background image and moves to another view.

This works fine, however, when I hit the back button, and go back to the original view, the navigation toolbar background image does not change back.

Here is the relevant code:

In my first view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //set to change the navigation toolbar to this background image (the first) when this view loads
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"QuickGrocery Logo Updated.jpg"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

button action:

```
    - (IBAction)wellBalancedMealsClicked:(id)sender {

    QuickGroceryMasterViewController *masterViewController = [[QuickGroceryMasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"QuickGroceryMasterViewController" bundle:nil];

    [masterViewController setRecipeChoice:1];

//changes the navigation toolbar background image
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Keep It Balanced.jpg"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

Comment: The reason your code is not working is that `viewDidLoad` is not called when returning to your first view controller. This method is only called when a view controller's views are loaded from a nib. Rob Mayoff's answer is the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

There's just one image for the navigation bar.  If you change it, and later you want it to change back, you have to change it back yourself.

I'd suggest you give each of your view controllers a `navigationBarImage` property.  Set a delegate for your navigation controller.  In the delegate, add this method:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIImage *image = [(id)viewController navigationBarImage];
    if (image)
        [navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

Comment: Rob, thanks for the help.  How do I "set a delegate" for the navigation controller?

Comment: Set the navigation controller's `delegate` property to an instance of a class that implements `navigationController:willShowViewController:`.

Comment: [Cocoa Core Competencies: Delegation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html)

Comment: Or do you mean "App Delegate"

Comment: The navigation controller can have a delegate.  That delegate can be the same object as the app delegate, or it can be a different object.

Comment: Rob, I'm sorry for pestering you, but I am new to objective-C and I am having trouble implementing this.  So, to clarify, I should place the method you provide above in my AppDelegate.m?  

There is an error that appears that says "No known instance method for selector "navigationBarImage" when I place this method in AppDelegate.m

Comment: After you add the `navigationBarImage` to your view controllers, make sure you import their header files in `AppDelegate.m` so it knows the `navigationBarImage` selector exists.